# Azure Databricks to Cognitive Search connection timing out

Tags: azure, search, databricks, private

I have a question on Azure Databricks and Azure Cognitive Search connectivity and hope this is the right forum to ask it.

We are getting a timeout message when creating an index , "ServiceRequestError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f081820e1a0>, 'Connection to xxxxx-aisearch-02.search.windows.net timed out. (connect timeout=300)')".  I recreated the scenario on my own subscription and get the same error message.

The command we are running is a simple create index one: "create_index('test22_index_db', config)". We've passed the search URL, Search Key and other parameters in the config variable.

The configuration uses private endpoints and all the configuration settings seem correct. Connectivity to other AI services is working fine, Document Intelligence and OpenAI services. Connectivity to storage accounts and keyvaults is fine as well.

Comment: This seems to work fine when I remove the private endpoint from AI Search. Does anyone have this working?

Comment: Having used Snowflake before, it has much better connectivity to other Azure Functions. I'll look into switching these workloads to Snowflake since this is really not working.

Comment: Utilize Azure Network Watcher's Connection Monitor & NSG Flow Logs to analyze traffic. Use nslookup in Databricks to resolve Cognitive Search's name to its private IP. Then, employ traceroute to visualize the network path for unexpected firewalls or routing issues. Address discrepancies found in configurations or routing to resolve connectivity problems.